# Truffle configuration, server.js instead of lite-server

Tags: truffle

As it seems lite-server is only good for development. I decided to use server.js for production but I have no idea how to configure it for truffle?

Comment: The title says "truffle instead of lite-server", the body says "server.js instead of lite-server". And the entire question is missing a lot of context IMO. You might want to elaborate a little further if you're hoping to get an answer.

Comment: @goodvibration you're right. I'll edit it soon. I actually solved the problem and It will be shared here.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned above, I experienced some problems to use server.js instead of lite-server. The solution is to include folders than I keep the web-application files and the compiled contracts. I created a server.js file and put the following script in it. Then I added

```
"start": "node server.js"
```

to the package.json's scripts part.

```
var connect = require('connect');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
connect()
.use(serveStatic('src'))
.use(serveStatic('build/contracts'))
.listen(80, function(){
    console.log('Server running on 80...');
});
```